# Update old Links to Windows Shares

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba, smb

Hello Windows network professionals,

assume that we have got a Windows network of over 1000 users has been running for over 10 years. The users have generated data and located them on different network shares over time.

There are tones of documents and elsewhere already where the data are addressed on the network, say e.g. with:

```
\\machine_1\robert\lab_tests\2009\measurements.dat
```

Recently a new server is set up to serve the same data over a new address:

```
\\machine_2\all_files\measurements.dat
```

The users can be advised to generate their **new data** under the new address, `\\machine_2\all_files`. Stopping shares totally on `machine_1`, however, make the links in the documents invalid. Is there a way to setup machine_1 so that it replaces/redirects all requests for `\\machine_1\robert\lab_tests\2009` to `\\machine_2\all_files`?

Comment: As you changed the directory structure no. Otherwise a simple DNS alias would've been sufficient.

Comment: Send an email with instructions that if they get this error when clicking on a shortcut icon, then they need to do this (navigate new location manually) and recreate any they get this message on by right-click, etc. Sounds like a ton of non-standard shortcut they create manually. If you had standard shortcut, you could have used Group Policy Preferences.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Could be good if there was a type of address translation or forwarding machanism that can be set up in Windows netwroks.